# On CentOS, mail or mutt never sends my emails

Tags: linux, centos, email, centos5, mutt

Using CentOS 5 and trying to send an email from the command line (for crontab emailing attachments).  mail and mutt execute without errors, but I just never receive any emails.  I'm running exim as the local smtp server.  My email address is a gmail account.

```
[root@server ~]# mail -s "hello subject" me@mygmaildomain.com < test_message.txt 
[root@server ~]# mutt -s "hello subject" me@mygmaildomain.com < test_message.txt 
[root@server ~]#
```

When I ran mutt by itself, it said there was no /var/spool/mail/root.  So I touched it:

```
[root@server ~]# touch /var/spool/mail/root
```

still no emails to my gmail account...  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check /var/log/maillog to see what errors (if any) are present.

/var/spool/mail/root is a local mailbox i.e. for incoming mail rather than an outgoing spool.

For outgoing mail, it's contained in /var/spool/mqueue

At least, this is where sendmail and postfix have their queues on CentOS, I'm not actually sure about exim, but it should be the same.

Comment: Ok, so I found a /var/log/exim/panic.log (many of them actually). And it had many lines ending with "User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list". Strange because this only yesterday started not emailing. I removed the never_users line from /etc/exim/exim.conf and now I get these, "User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the fixed_never_users list." Figuring out how to solve that...

Comment: Ah.. yeah.. Exim compiles in the option to never send as root. Can you send as another user? Maybe the easiest way forward is to switch to Postfix or something. Recompiling exim is probably not the way you want to go.

Comment: Ok, so I got this to work by specifying an alias for root in /etc/aliases.  The problem now is my SMTP provider, AuthSMTP, requires certain from addresses, so email is being rejected by them, "SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<root@server.localdomain> SIZE=1800: host mail.authsmtp.com [62.13.128.193]: 500 5.0.0 Envelope From Address of <root@server.localdomain> is not authorised - go to: http
://control.authsmtp.com".  I need exim to go through AuthSMTP for other uses.  How can I specify a from address in mutt or another command line email client that can attach files?

Comment: I use AuthSMTP too. Use a ~/.muttrc file and specify the following: set use_from=yes        set from="me@mydomain.com"      set realname="My Name"    (sorry, bad formatting ... not sure how to format these things in comments)

Comment: I used those settings and even restarted exim, but they didn't work.  Got the same error message in the /var/log/exim/main.log.  The problem is that it doesn't change the MAIL FROM: header when exim talks to AuthSMTP.

Comment: I've added "set envelope_from=yes" to my .muttrc in addition to the parameters given by Rafiq.